# spring jdbc crud save creates duplicate record in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

i have credit transaction table in postgresql as below

```
id  | vh_owner_id | credit | debit  | created_dttm |  modified_dttm  | is_deleted 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  1          | 0      | 1000   | 19-dec-2021   |    null           0
```

i have backend service in spring boot and when i do  spring crud save operation; it is creating two rows , but this is not happening for all credit transaction, it is happening intermittently.

in my logic, i have below spring boot java service as

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public CreditTransactionMO createCreditTransaction(CreditTransactionMO creditTransactionMO) throws Exception {
    //getting last entered credit transaction based on created dttm for the customer
    CreditTransaction creditTransaction = creditTransactionRepo
            .findTopByVhOwnerIdOrderByCreatedDttmDesc(creditTransactionMO.getVhOwner().getId());
    if ( condition check) {
        double totalOutstanding = creditTransactionMO.getCredit() + creditTransaction.getCredit()
                - creditTransaction.getDebit();
        
        CreditTransaction newCreditTrans = new CreditTransaction();
        if (totalOutstanding < 0) {
            
            double totalCredit = creditTransaction.getCredit() + creditTransactionMO.getCredit();
            mapMOtoDO(creditTransactionMO, creditTransaction);
            creditTransaction.setCredit(totalCredit);
            // update transactions with new credit amt
            creditTransaction = creditTransactionRepo.save(creditTransaction);

            // create new debit transaction 
            creditTransactionMO.setId(creditTransaction.getId());
            newCreditTrans.setVhOwnerId(creditTransactionMO.getVhOwner().getId());
            double newDebit = (-1 * totalOutstanding);
            newCreditTrans.setDebit(newDebit);

            //this is latest credit transaction
            // this transaction is creating two rows, instead of one row.
            creditTransactionRepo.save(newCreditTrans);
```

how to avoid save operation from creating duplicate rows. And current table design doesn't have any unique column to avoid this duplicate.. looking for better way to handle this, since it is transaction table, i dont want to add more complexity by adding extra constraints to the table design.

Comment: Using a unique constraint (and handling the errors) is the best way to ensure uniqueness

Comment: but in my table, i cant make any column to unique.. is there any other option available to avoid this?